# Why doesn't the HashMap "contain" the keys that are internally changed only?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, identity

In my program, I have a HashMap. It has HashSets of Strings as its keys and PriorityQueues of Strings as its values. When I change the content of one of its keys, it is no longer remain as a member of the HashMap. This seems strange to me, since I do not change the reference of the key. I just change its content. Please take a look at the following snippet:

```
HashMap<HashSet<String>, PriorityQueue<String>> myHashMap=new HashMap<>();

HashSet<String> myHashSet=new HashSet<>();
myHashSet.add("abc");
myHashSet.add("mnq");
myHashSet.add("al;ksghl");

PriorityQueue<String> myPriorityQueue=new PriorityQueue<>();
myPriorityQueue.add("3h4");
myPriorityQueue.add("lskdjf");

myHashMap.put(myHashSet, myPriorityQueue);

if(myHashMap.containsKey(myHashSet))
    System.out.println("Yes!");

myHashSet.remove("abc");

if(myHashMap.containsKey(myHashSet))
    System.out.println("Yes!");
```

Basically, I expect to see two "Yes!"s, indeed, it prints only one. I did a thorough debugging and realized that the reference number for myHashSet doesn't change after removing one of it's members. So, there should be no reason for this program not to print the second "Yes!".

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Comment: Usage of the container as a key is very bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hashmap keys off the hash/equals of the key (which has been pointed out, is changing). If you care about identity, you should use an java.util.IdentityHashMap

Answer (score 6):

Changing the contents of your set changes its identity and hash code. Since the map uses `equals` and `hashCode` to look up and compare its keys, this breaks the integrity of the map, which manifests in the set no longer being found.

To quote from [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects `equals` comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

Try adding the line

```
System.out.println(myHashSet.hashCode());
```

before and after the `remove` call to see the difference.